# How to extract XML data and reflect it on another webpage?

Tags: xml, jsp, coordinates

I want to be able to extract the data from the XML file and reflect it on another webpage. The data's positions should be exactly where it was saved.

```
<%
    FileWriter      fw = new FileWriter     ( request.getRealPath("/") + "conf/taskcard2.xml", false);
    BufferedWriter  br = new BufferedWriter ( fw);
    PrintWriter     pw = new PrintWriter    ( br);

    pw.println      ( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>" );
    pw.println      ( "<TemplateEditor>");

    String value = request.getParameter("movableItems");
    String[] items = value.split("\\|");
    int size = items.length;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        String[] data = items[i].split(",");
        pw.println      ( "\t<Logo>");
        pw.print        ( "\t\t<Number>");              pw.print (Integer.valueOf(data[0])+1);          pw.println ( "</Number>");
        pw.print        ( "\t\t<X_Coord>");             pw.print (data[1]);             pw.println ( "</X_Coord>");
        pw.print        ( "\t\t<Y_Coord>");             pw.print (data[2]);             pw.println ( "</Y_Coord>");
        pw.print        ( "\t\t<Width>");               pw.print (data[3]);             pw.println ( "</Width>");
        pw.print        ( "\t\t<Height>");              pw.print (data[4]);             pw.println ( "</Height>");
        pw.println      ( "\t</Logo>");
    }

    pw.println      ( "</TemplateEditor>");
    pw.flush(); 
    pw.close();
    br.close();
    fw.close();

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) or [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) to parse the `XML` document and try to [avoid Java code in JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).